# Force OS X to recognize iPhone as a drive

Tags: macos, mount

Hey, I have an iPhone 3G synced to a dead computer. I have a different computer running Snow Leopard that I want to use to pull the photos off the phone (and, ideally, add/remove music). iTunes keeps you from doing this by making sure the phone can only sync with one library at a time. I'm aware there are a couple logistical options for recovering the data, but my question is OS X-centric:

How do I force OS X to recognize the iPhone as a drive when it's connected?

iTunes or some related service is keeping the system from mounting the drive. i.e. if I were to plug the phone into a Windows or Linux machine, the phone would show as a removable disk and I could browse the folder containing the photos. What is the process running that is responsible, and is there a way around it?

Comment: (Hopefully the iPhone part of this question doesn't disqualify it from being asked - I want to know what is happening on the OSX side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this lifehacker article:
[Disk for iPhone Turns Your iPhone into a Portable Drive](http://lifehacker.com/5152377/disk-for-iphone-turns-your-iphone-into-a-portable-drive)

> Disk for iPhone is a free application
>   that mounts your iPhone or iPod touch
>   as a drive on your Mac, turning your
>   device into a portable hard drive.

[image]

Comment: thanks! this caused it to show up in iPhoto as well. excellent!

Comment: Doesn't work with 64bit kernels, ... so it doesn't work with 10.7 running on recent hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application phoneview that may help:

http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

(Mac only)

Comment: Cost: $19.95 [15 chars]

Comment: Yeah, I did not say it is free. If you do not want install MacFUSE for some reason, it gets the job done.

This app was also part of the MacHeist deals and quite a few people have it without knowing it. If you ever participated in MacHeist, check your "lootbag"